# How to change input submit text value when submitting on AMP?

Tags: amp-html

I have a simple amp form in which I would like to change the text of the input submit when the form is submitting:

```
<form method="POST" class="p2" action-xhr=".../api/contacts" custom- 
  validation-reporting="as-you-go" target="_top">
 <input name="phone" id="phone_input" required>

 //Change the value from Submit to Submitting... when the user clicks
 <input id="btn-form-submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
  <div id="submit-success" submit-success>
    <template type="amp-mustache">
       <h6>Success!</h6>
    </template>
  </div>
</form>
```

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Two options come to mind:

1. **Use [`amp-bind`](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-bind) and bind the `value` of your button to a state.**

   Add some start state:

   ```
   <amp-state id="formText">
     <script type="application/json">
       {
         "submit": "Submit"
       }
     </script>
   </amp-state>
   ```

   Then use `[value]` to bind this state to your button:

   ```
   <input id="btn-form-submit"
          type="submit"
          value="Submit"
          [value]="formText.submit">
   ```

   Finally, call `AMP.setState` on the `submit` event of the form to change state which will result in changing your bound attribute (you'll probably want to also use the `submit-success` and `submit-error` events to bring it back to "Submit"):

   ```
   <form method="POST"
         class="p2"
         action-xhr=".../api/contacts"
         on="submit:AMP.setState({formText: {submit: 'Submitting'}}); submit-success:AMP.setState({formText: {submit: 'Submit'}}); submit-error:AMP.setState({formText: {submit: 'Submit'}})">
   ```
2. **Use the CSS [`:before` pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) on a `<button>` to dynamically change the text.**

   Replace your `<input>` with `<button>`:

   ```
   <button id="btn-form-submit" type="submit" aria-label="Submit"></button>
   <!-- We removed <input id="btn-form-submit" type="submit" value="Submit"> -->
   ```

   Now use the [`content` CSS attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) to provide the button text, both for the base case ("Submit") and when submitting:

   ```
   #btn-form-submit:before {
       content: "Submit";
   }

   form.amp-form-submitting #btn-form-submit:before {
       content: "Submitting";
   }
   ```